# Pseudometrics on world lines

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, lorentzian-geometry

Consider the space $W$ of smooth time-like curves in $\mathbb{R}^{n,1}$ with fixed ends.
Given $\gamma\in W$, consider the space $T_\gamma$ of all smooth normal fields along $\gamma$;
one may think that $T_\gamma$ is a tangent space of $W$ at $\gamma$.
Each normal space to $\gamma$ has natural Euclidean structure.
Therefore, the space $T_\gamma$ can be equipped with various norms, say $\|V\|=\sqrt{\int_\gamma|V|^2}$ or $\|V\|=\int_\gamma|V|$.
These norms can be used to define pseudometrics on $W$.

> Have this been studied? Do these norms and pseudometrics have names?

> Is it known when the obtained pseudometric is a genuine metric?

Comment: I guess $V$ vanish at the ends of $\gamma$; otherwise it is not in the tangent space to $W$.

Comment: If $n=1$, then the norm $\|V\|=\int_\gamma|V|$ corresspond to the area between two world lines. So, it defines a genuine metric.

Comment: It seems that if $n\ge 2$, then the pseudometric defined by $\|V\|=\int_\gamma|V|$ (and therefore all $L^p$-norms) vanish. Indeed, you may approximate your world line by zig-zag null-curve and any two zig-zag-null-curves can be connected to each other by a a surface with vanishing area.